# OWA 2007 integration

Tags: jquery, asp.net, exchange-server, outlook-web-app

I have been tasked with integrating OWA 2007 into an existing ASP.net (jQuery enhanced) website.  I am currently researching how to display a "Compose" dialog when a user clicks on a mailto: link but am having some issues.  In previous versions of OWA it was as easy as referencing:

```
http://mailserver/exchange/username/?cmd=new
```

I cannot seem to find the OWA 2007 way to accomplish this.  In fact, the documentation I can find that references the cmd querystring parameter only shows it with a value of cmd=contents.

Documentation:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb232199.aspx

http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2006/10/26/3395220.aspx

Attempting the following does not work as expected:

```
http://mailserver/owa/username/?cmd=new
```

or

```
http://mailserver/owa/username/?cmd=new&f=inbox
```

Has anyone had any luck with this sort of implementation?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for OWA Webparts is located here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb232199(EXCHG.80).aspx. That's the documentation for Exchange 2007. If you don't find your answer there, you'll probably have to build it yourself.